# Debug Change finding using Memoization

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming

From the last couple of hours, I have been trying to debug this code.

**Problem**: Given a set of coins: 1, 5, 10, 21 and 25 write an algorithm that finds change for a given amount using the minimum possible number of coins.

Ex: if the amount is 63, it should return 3 [21, 21, 21]

**My Code:**

```
def change_rec_memo(change_list, amount, memo):
    if amount in change_list:
        memo[amount] = (1, [amount])
        return 1, [amount]
    if amount in memo:
        return memo[amount]
    mini, values, min_coin = None, [], None
    for coin in change_list:
        if amount - coin > 0:
            count, sub_values = change_rec_memo(change_list, amount-coin, memo)
            if mini is None:
                mini = count
                values = sub_values
                min_coin = coin
            if count < mini:
                mini = count
                values = sub_values
                min_coin = coin
    values.append(min_coin)
    memo[amount] = (mini+1, values)
    return mini+1, values


def main():
    print change_rec_memo([1, 5, 10, 21, 25], 52, {})
```

The code seems to work fine for most of the cases, but fails for cases like 52, 63. It outputs the correct number of coins but the coin_listing contains extra coins.

Here is a Python Fiddle for it: https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/08b3da45-0c0d-464a-b025-00d215bc4634/?i=true

Comment: You're mutating the memo entries.

Comment: I am only assigning values and reading from it, I am not modifying it, except maybe for the base case, where I am.

Comment: `values.append(min_coin)` - think about what `values` is, and where it came from. (Some [reading](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) may be helpful.)

Comment: @user2357112 Nice observation, dude.

Comment: @user2357112: I just feel like pulling my hair out !! All I needed to do was: **values = sub_values[:]** and everything is working as expected !!! The funny thing is I knew that python refers to objects by reference, still made that mistake !!

Answer (score 0):

there is one more readable and shorter example.and use stack variable(the parameter of recursive function)

```
import sys
@functools.lru_cache()
def change_rec_memo(change_list, amount, count):
    if amount == 0:
        return count
    if len(change_list) == 0 or amount < 0:return sys.maxsize
    if amount - change_list[-1] >= 0:
        return min(change_rec_memo(change_list,amount - change_list[-1], count +1),change_rec_memo(change_list[:-1], amount, count))
    else:
        return change_rec_memo(change_list[:-1], amount, count)
print(change_rec_memo((1, 5, 10, 21, 25), 215,0))
```